# Using Bluez (with C) to receive BLE notifications

Tags: c, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm looking for an example (without having to reverse engineering hcitool and/or gatttool) for using Bluez (C api) to pair a "peripheral sensor", read/write characteristics, and receive notifications from the peripheral.   Pointers to an example or documentation would be appreciated!   Thanks!